# How can I have multiple URLs pointing to single WordPress installation?

Tags: multisite, urls, subdomains

Here's my scenario:

I have three specific jobs sites: 
LAMPJobsLA.com, MobileJobsLA.com,  SocialMediaJobsLA.com

I'd like to run them under on "master site": TechJobsLA.com 
but keep the URLs intact when a visitor lands on the page with the posts matching the categories or tags (taxonomy).

For example, if someone visits MobileJobsLA.com, the two URLs that would both work are:
http://techjobsla.com/tag/mobile-ios-android/ 
or 
http://mobilejosbsla.com/ default page redirects to ---> http://mobilejosbsla.com/tag/mobile-ios-android

Hope that makes sense.

I see from some of the previous questions/answers, WordPress MU Domain Mapping plugin might work for me.

Answer (score 1):

> I see from some of the previous questions/answers, WordPress MU Domain Mapping plugin might work for me.

As long as you've created a network first, yes. this is what you need.

Then to pump them all to the main site, use this:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-sitewide-tags/

That's pretty much it.